# Count how many occurrences of substrings within a string without counting duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, algorithm

For example, I have a list of terms and a string:

```
var terms = { "programming language", "programming", "language" };

var content = "A programming language is a formal language that "
    + "specifies a set of instructions that can be used to "
    + "produce various kinds of output.";
```

I can use `Regex.Matches(content, term).Count` to count that there are 4 times the list appear in the string:

- "programming language": 1 time
- "programming": 1 time
- "language": 2 times

But there are duplicates, there should be only 2 occurrences.

My current solution is to save the begin index and end index of each occurrence, then compare to the saved occurences wherever it is in range and has already been count. Is there a better way without using start and end indexes?

Comment: How do you build your regex? `(programming language|programming|language)` should do what you want, if you do it right.

Comment: Show what you´ve tried before.

Comment: What do you mean without counting duplicates? You want to count occurrences so by definition you are going to count duplicates. Could you explain more?

Comment: @ThomasCook I count how many occurrences of the whole substring list. `programming language` contains `programming` and `language`, so I don't need to count these again.

Comment: Got you, ok and are you running the regex in one go or are you splitting it?

If you are splitting it then it's simple, run the more specific regex first and just maintain a hash set of already found terms. Do not run a regex if what it's looking for is contained in the hashset.

If it's all running as part of one regex then I can't help you, although I'm sure there's probably a way.

Comment: Why you need to add `"programming language"` at all? You are already counting `programming` and `language` so you would always have a match here too. Just remove the `programming language` from the array.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because `programming language` counts as one term, if I remove it the current example would return 3 occurrences, not 2 as I expected.

Comment: @MiP: why? If you count in this way: `terms.Count(content.Contains)` you get only 2 then

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought `Count` worked with an accumulator, so `programming` occur once and `language` occur twice, after summing doesn't it return 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestions from comments, I have a [simple solution](https://regex101.com/r/95YkkX/2) using regex, it should work with exact whole word, i.e. `programming language` can be counted but `programming languages` cannot:

```
var pattern = @"(?<!\S)programming language(?![^\s])|(?<!\S)programming(?![^\s])|(?<!\S)language(?![^\s])";
var count = Regex.Matches(content, pattern).Count;
```

Note: this pattern can only be used when `programming language` is placed before `programming` and `language` terms. If anyone can contribute a better solution, please do so.

Comment: You can probably use `\b` instead of `(?<!\S)` or `(?![^\s])` to detect word edges. Other than that, all you have left to do is find a way to automatically order the search terms...

Comment: @Rawling I'm new at regex, could you please write an example using `\b` to detect edges?

Comment: Something like `\b(xy|y|z)\b`. `\b` matches the point between a word character (letter, number, underscore) and a non-word character (anything else).